# Background colour for directlabels & ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's some test data:

```
y <- c(1:10, 6:15)
b <- c(rep(c("A", "B"), each=10))
x <- 1:10
df <- data.frame(b, x, y)
```

And a test plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=b)) + geom_line()
direct.label(p1, list("first.points", hjust=-1, vjust=-0.5))
```

[image]

I'd like the background of the labels to be white (in a rectangle around the text). Is there a way to achieve that? I tried `fill="white"`, `colour="white"`, `background="white"`, nothing happened..

Comment: Have you tried `theme_set(theme_bw())`? Maybe you get a warning, but it should work fine.

Comment: [**This Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815672/how-can-i-configure-box-color-in-directlabels-draw-rects) may be helpful.

Comment: @Henrik, thanks, `my.dl <- list(box.color="white", "draw.rects"); direct.label(p1, list("first.points", hjust=-1, vjust=-0.5, "calc.boxes", "my.dl"))` works!

Comment: @beetroot, can you please write up an answer with your code and the resulting plot? Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik, sure, done!

Comment: @beetroot, Great! I think you can [**accept your own answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after 48 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, thanks to Henrik's comment pointing to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815672/how-can-i-configure-box-color-in-directlabels-draw-rects) I came up with this:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=b)) + geom_line()

my.dl <- list(box.color="white", "draw.rects")
direct.label(p1, list("first.points", hjust=-1, vjust=-0.3, "calc.boxes", "my.dl"))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your only adaption your code requires is `theme_set(theme_bw())`

```
y <- c(1:10, 6:15)
b <- c(rep(c("A", "B"), each=10))
x <- 1:10
df <- data.frame(b, x, y)

theme_set(theme_bw())  # added
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=b)) + geom_line()
direct.label(p1, list("first.points", hjust=-1, vjust=-0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I am looking for, I want the background of the letter to be white, too.

Comment: ah, I see, sorry, then @Henrik 's hint may be helpful!