# Using direct.labels within a loop in ggplot for geom_contour

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, contour

**Edited with an example of my dataset"

I'm currently working on a loop in R to produce 21 contour plots from 21 model output spreadsheets in ggplot. The entire loop is now working and printing to a single pdf, but I would like to add direct.labels to each plot along the contours. I'm not confident in how to do this whilst making sure the loop still executes?

My data:

```
x      y      z
0.175  1.97   1113.17
0.175  1.975  1112.31
0.175  1.98   1111.44
0.175  1.985  1110.66
0.175  1.99   1109.72
0.175  1.995  1109.28
0.175  2      1107.6
0.18   0      1321.99
0.18   0.005  1321.99
0.18   0.01   1321.99
0.18   0.015  1321.99
0.18   0.02   1321.99
0.18   0.025  1321.99
0.18   0.03   1321.99
0.18   0.035  1321.99
0.18   0.04   1321.99
```

My code:

```
filenames <- list.files(path=".",
                    pattern="csv", 
                    full.names=TRUE)
pdfnames <- paste(substr(filenames, 1, nchar(filenames)-4),".pdf",sep="")
pdfmaster <- paste(substr(filenames,1,15),".pdf",sep="")

# List of variables being displayed
variable = c("Dimensionless potential temperature", 
         "Melt fraction",
         "Melting rate",
         ...)

#Creates a contour plot in ggplot of the variable in xz space
makeplot <- function(filename) {
xx <- which(filenames==filename)
  data <- as.data.frame(read.csv(file=filename), header = FALSE)
  ggplot(data=data, mapping = aes(x = data[,2], 
                              y=data[,1], 
                              z = data[,3])) +

    geom_raster(data=data, aes(fill=data[,3]), show.legend=TRUE, interpolate         
 = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_gradient(limits=range(data[,3]), high = 'red', low = 'white')   +
    geom_contour(bins = 30, colour = "black") +
    xlab(label = "Distance from ridge axis") +
    ylab(label = "Depth") +
    theme_bw()+
    coord_cartesian(
      ylim = c(0,1), xlim = c(0,2))+
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title=variable[xx]), 
           guide_colorbar(title=NULL)) 

}

# Making one pdf file per plot
for (f in 1:length(filenames)) {
  pdf(file=pdfnames[f], height=3, width=6)
  print(makeplot(filenames[f]))
  dev.off()
}

# Making all plots in one pdf
pdf(file=pdfmaster[1], height=6, width=12)
for (f in 1:length(filenames)) {
  print(makeplot(filenames[f]))
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `direct labels`? Do you want to add text to each individual plots?

Comment: I want to label the contours with their values, which I think you can do via the 'direct.labels' package - I've looked at this similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154679/r-adding-legend-and-directlabels-to-ggplot2-contour-plot  - however I can't get this to work inside my loop

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Hi I've updated this with a sample of my data, sorry about that